# Css Layering Issue

Tags: css

I am having allot of trouble with layering, My current issue is that vistors can not click on links inside div layers for some reason. They can't highlight text, click on the images in the sidebar which are linked up. I don't know what is wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Arakion - Homepage</title>
<html>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="js/video-js/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="js/video-js/video.js"></script>
  <script>
    _V_.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
  </script>
<style type = "text/css">
body {background-color:#FFFFFF; background-size:contain;} 
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

function chgbg() {
var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHours();

if ((h >= 6) && (h < 9)) {document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"; document.body.style.backgroundImage="url(images/Backgrounds/Night.png)"}
if ((h >= 9) && (h < 20)) {document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"; document.body.style.backgroundImage="url(images/Backgrounds/Night.png)"}
if ((h >= 20) && (h < 22)) {document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"; document.body.style.backgroundImage="url(images/Backgrounds/Night.png)"}
if ((h >= 22) || (h<6)) {document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"; document.body.style.backgroundImage="url(images/Backgrounds/Night.png)"}

}
</script> 
</head>
<body onload="chgbg()">
<div id="Wrapper">
  <div id="navbar" style="display: inline-block;">
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="top">
        <a href="home:index.html">HOME</a>
    </li>

    <li id="top">
        <a href="#">GUIDE</a>
        <ul>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/classes.php">CLASSES</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/dungeons.php">DUNGEONS</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/monsters.php">MONSTERS</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/pets.php">PETS</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/races.php">RACES</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/town buildings.php">TOWN BUILDINGS</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/universe.php">UNIVERSE</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/wiki.php">WIKI</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="top">
        <a href="#">BLOG</a>

        <ul>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/arakion.php">ARAKION</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/chris taylor.php">CHRIS TAYLOR</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li id="top">
        <a href="#">MEDIA</a>
        <ul>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/art.php">CONCEPT ART</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/screenshots.php">SCREENSHOTS</a></li>
        <li id="submenu"><a href="Htdocs/videos.php">VIDEOS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="top">
        <a href="Php/forum/index.php">FORUM</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="sidebar_header"><div id="Kickstarter_progressbar"></div></div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="sidebar_banner"><div id="Kickstarter_donationcount"><a>$20,000</a></div>
  <div id="Sidebar_content">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="title">Social Media</p>
    <p><img src="images/Side Banner_Line.png" width="100%" height="10"  class="title" /></p>
    <p><a href="http://www.indiedb.com/games/arakion" target="_new"><img src="images/IndieDBIcon.png" width="35" height="35" /></a> 
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/Arakion" target="_new"><img src="images/FacebookIcon.png" width="35" height="35" /></a> <a href="http://twitter.com/arakiongame" target="_new"> 
            <img src="images/TwitterICon.png" width="35" height="35" /> </a> <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/MrLavidimus" target="_new"> <img src="images/YoutubeICon.png" width="35" height="35" /> </a> </p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Random Media</p>
    <p><img src="images/Side Banner_Line.png" width="100%" height="10" /></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Something</p>
    <p><img src="images/Side Banner_Line.png" width="100%" height="10" /></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div></div>
<div style="display: inline-block;" id="main_background">
  <div id="main_content"><div id="main_img"><img src="images/MainImages/Main_Placeholder_img.jpg"/></div>
    <table width="600" height="106" border="0" id="main_section_img" style="margin:0 auto; vertical-align:top; margin-top: 0;">
      <tr>
        <td width="140"><img src="images/MainImages/Placeholder1.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></td>
        <td width="140"><img src="images/MainImages/Placeholder2.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></td>
        <td width="140"><img src="images/MainImages/Placeholder3.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></td>
        <td width="140"><img src="images/MainImages/Placeholder4.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="140">How Housing Works and why we have it    <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
        <td width="140">An In depth look at the Satyr race  <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
        <td width="140">We take a look at the role the alchemist plays in a group   <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
        <td width="140">Our doors are offically open to new employees apply today   <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div></div>

<div style="display: inline-block;" id="sub_background_1"><div id="sub_content">
  <div id="Sub_title">Kickstarter has just opened!</div>
  <div id="Sub_subtitle">by Chris Taylor 7-24-2012</div>
  <div id="Sub_image" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="images/MainImages/Sub_Placeholder.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></div>
  <div id="Sub_text"> sUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
    adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
    proident, <a href="index.html">Read More.</a></div></div></div>

<div style="display: inline-block;" id="sub_background_2"><div id="sub_content">
  <div id="Sub_title">Kickstarter has just opened!</div>
  <div id="Sub_subtitle">by Chris Taylor 7-24-2012</div>
  <div id="Sub_image" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="images/MainImages/Sub_Placeholder.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></div>
  <div id="Sub_text"> sUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
    adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
    proident, <a href="index.html">Read More.</a></div></div></div>

 <div style="display: inline-block;" id="sub_background_3"><div id="sub_content">
  <div id="Sub_title">Kickstarter has just opened!</div>
  <div id="Sub_subtitle">by Chris Taylor 7-24-2012</div>
  <div id="Sub_image" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="images/MainImages/Sub_Placeholder.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></div>
  <div id="Sub_text"  style="z-index:9;"> 
    <video id="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264"
      poster="js/video-js/Posters/Test.png"
      data-setup="{}">
    <source src="js/video-js/Videos/Test.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <track kind="captions" src="captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English" />
  </video>
   <a href="index.html">Read More.</a></div></div></div>

 <div style="display: inline-block;" id="sub_background_4"><div id="sub_content">
  <div id="Sub_title">Kickstarter has just opened!</div>
  <div id="Sub_subtitle">by Chris Taylor 7-24-2012</div>
  <div id="Sub_image" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="images/MainImages/Sub_Placeholder.jpg"  height="100%" width="100%"/></div>
  <div id="Sub_text"> sUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
    adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
    proident, <a href="index.html">Read More.</a></div></div></div>

<div id="footer_background" style=" text-align: center; ">
    <img src="images/Footer_Divider.png" height="10px" width="600px"/>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
COPYRIGHT 2012 CHRIS TAYLOR ALL RIGHTS RESERVED | CODED BY SEAN HALL</a></div>
        <div id="left"><img src="images/Backgrounds/Left.png" width="320" height="802" /></div>
        <div id="right"><img src="images/Backgrounds/Right.png" width="333" height="833" /></div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'KingthingsExeterRegular';
    src: url('font/kingthings_exeter-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/kingthings_exeter-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font/kingthings_exeter-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/kingthings_exeter-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/kingthings_exeter-webfont.svg#KingthingsExeterRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
body {
    font-family: 'KingthingsExeterRegular';
    overflow-y: auto;
}
body,td,th {
    font-family: KingthingsExeterRegular;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    zoom: 110%
}
a:link {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*Body Css */
#header{
  z-index: -999;
  width:900px ;
  height:800px ;
  position: relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
#left{
  z-index:-9;
  width:239px;
  height:600px ;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  position: absolute;
  left:-215px;
  top:150px;
}
#right{
  z-index:-2;
  width:239px;
  height:600px ;
  float:right;
  clear: both;
  position: absolute;
  left:960px;
  top:120px;
}
#Wrapper {
    width:1040px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:-40px;
    height:2000px;
    position: relative; 
    z-index:0;
}
/*------------------------------------*\
    NAV
\*------------------------------------*/
#navbar{
    position: relative;
    top:91px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:5px;
    width:649px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index:4;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    clear:both;
}
#nav{
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:600;
    height:50;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
#top{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url("images/Button_NavBar_Unselected.png");
    height:55px;
    width:119px;
    font-size:15px;
}
#top:hover{
    background-image:url("images/Button_NavBar_Hover.png")
}
#submenu{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    height:18px;
    width:110px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align:center;
}
#submenu_bottem{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    height:18px;
    width:110px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align:center;
}
#nav a{
    display:block;
    padding-top:20px;
    z-index:-1;
    font-family:"Arial";
}
/*--- DROPDOWN ---*/
#nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px;
    height:18px; 
}
#nav ul li{
    padding-top:1px; 
    float:none;
}
#nav ul a{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#nav li:hover ul{ 
    left:-30px;
    top:40px;
}
#nav li:hover ul a{ /* The persistent hover state does however create a global style for links even before they're hovered. Here we undo these effects. */

}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover{ /* Here we define the most explicit hover states--what happens when you hover each individual link. */

}
/* Main Block */
#main_background{
    width:680px;
    height:519px;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(images/MainSection.png);
}
#main_content{
    width:590px;
    height:430px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:45px;
}
#main_img{
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:5px;
    background-image:url(images/MainSection_BigImageHighlight.png);
    width:520px;
    height:300px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:4px;
}
#main_section_img{
    margin-top:10px;
    background-image:url(mages/MainSection_SmallImageInsett.png);
    width:560px;
    height:95px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:top; 
    margin-top:0; 
}
#main_section_img td{
    vertical-align:top; 
    margin-top:0; 
}
/* Sub Block */
/*  Sub Background Hierarchy */
#sub_background_1{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-1;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-38px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_2{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-2;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-52px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_3{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-3;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-65px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_4{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-4;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-77px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_5{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-5;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-83px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_6{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-6;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-81px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_7{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-7;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-81px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#sub_background_8{
    position:relative;
    width:610px;
    height:270px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(images/SubSection_Base.png);
    z-index:-8;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:-85px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
/* Hierarchy End */
#sub_content{
    width:580px;
    height:220px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    clear: both;
}
#Sub_title{
    height:35px;
    width:400px;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left:10px;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align: left;
}
#Sub_subtitle{
    height:20px;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:65;
    font-size:15px;
    text-align: left;
}
#Sub_image{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:15px;
    float:left;
}
#Sub_text{
    height:180px;
    width:400px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:5px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index:9;
    position: relative;
}
/* SideBar Block */
#sidebar_header{
    position:relative;
    height:80px;
    width:350px;
    float:right;
    background-image:url(images/Kickstarter.png);
    margin-right:5px;
    left:-20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    z-index:1;
    clear: both;
    top:1px;
}
#sidebar_banner{
    position:relative;
    height:729px;
    width:360px;
    float:right;
    background-image: url(images/Side%20Banner.png);
    left:-20px;
    z-index:-1;
    clear: both;
}
#Sidebar_content{
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:20px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 20px;
    width:300px;
    height:700px;
    line-height: 3px;
}
#Kickstarter_donationcount{
    width: 119px;
    height: 26px;
    text-align:center;
    top:8px;
    left:230px;
    background-image:url("images/Progress/GoalNumber.png");
    position: absolute;
    padding-top:6px;
}
#Kickstarter_progressbar{
    position:relative;
    top:62px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 310px;
    height: 18px;
    background-image:url("images/Progress/KickstarterGoalBar_100.png")
}
#Kickstarter_donationcount a {
        color: #000;
        font:"arial";
        font-size: 18px;
}
#Sidebar_content .title{
    line-break: 1px;
}
/* Footer */
#footer_background{
    position:relative;
    background-image:url(images/Footer.png);
    width:605px;
    height:75px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:35px;
    top:-89px;
    z-index:-9;
    line-height:1px;
    font-family:"Arial";
    font-size:12px;
}
#footer_background a:link{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#footer_background img {
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

Comment: In what browser does this happens? *Can't repro in Win7 FF14!*

Comment: I'm able to click all links, but the div height for the left column is being overflowed with text (too many lines for the space available.)

Answer (score 2):

Wrapper is covering other stuff so you want to just push it to the bottom. Add `z-index: 0;` to `#wrapper`.

Or you can remove the `z-index: -1` from the divs inside `#wrapper`

In the future, post only relevant code inside the post. Nobody will bother going through your site to figure out the issue for you. If you can't narrow the problem down to something specific, then you need to troubleshoot better.

Comment: **How can this be right?** All elements are inside the wrapper, `z-index` or no `z-index`, will make no difference.

Comment: Thanks, Adding Z-inded:0; Has Worked. Also I will bear that in mind for future posts and I need z-index: -1's So the background layers are under the other. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

While sachleen's answer did provide a workaround for your imminent problem, your page is facing several critical issues that will become problems very soon.

### Give me the code!

Here's the link to your page fully working and without any validation issues. Images are not optimized, but I had to adapt one of them to prevent the usage of z-index all the time:

- [View it online](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/75546013/stackoverflow/11711240/index.html)
- [Download the files](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/75546013/stackoverflow/11711240/11711240.zip)

*Compare the files with your own and see what has been done to improve and make the document valid.*

### Here's a list of the most significant issues:

1. **Element ID**

   Elements can have an ID, but the ID must be unique on the page, this because the ID purpose is to identify a specific element. If you need to provide a style to multiple elements, the proper way is to use classes.

   From [MDN :: id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/id)

   > A unique identifier so that you can identify the element with. You can use this as a parameter to getElementById() and other DOM functions and to reference the element in style sheets.
2. **Images**

   While this is more related with performance, I'm sure that visitors of this webpage will not be please to have to wait a considerable amount of time while 4Mb of images that you currently use get downloaded.

   You can use [Google Pagespeed Tools](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/), that provides you with a tool to analyze the webpage for errors, and also if images aren't optimized, a link is presented on the analyse report to download an optimized version.
3. **Document Stack**

   This is the reason as to why you've placed your question. You are messing around with your document stack to overcome issues that should be solved with images usage or a proper markup. While you're free to move elements up and down within the document stack, your page will be facing issues when it comes to cross-browser compatibilities.

   The document stack should be used to overcome small details or provide a way to interact with the user without forcing a page refresh, among others. Shouldn't be used for the majority of the elements present as a way to solve layout issues.
4. **Document Type**

   The document type is used to tell the browser how we should interpreter the document, and what rules should be respected to present it the way you intended.

   > When authoring document is HTML or XHTML, it is important to Add a Doctype declaration. The doctype declaration must be exact (both in spelling and in case) to have the desired effect, which makes it sometimes difficult.

   You can read about it at [W3c - Doctype Declarations](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html)
5. **HTML Markup**

   Your page lacks a proper markup, that in turn will prevent the browser from presenting elements the way they are supposed to be presented.

   You can read about it at [W3C - HTML: The Markup Language](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/)

   Additionally, you can use the [W3C validation service](http://validator.w3.org/) to validate and identify issues with your HTML Markup. Keep in mind that recent features aren't properly validated, mainly with CSS. But that's just a small portion.